# Passing value from textbox to http adapter failed mobilefirst platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm trying to pass some values from a textbox to an http adapter and it have the following error:

Here is the **index.html**

```
  Username:<br>
   <input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
    Password:<br>
   <input type="text" name="password" id="password"><br>

    <button onclick="mobgetVerify()">Login</button>
    <p> 
    <p id="demo"></p> <br />        
    <br />
    <br />
```

**mains.js**

```
function mobgetVerify() {

   alert("Hi" + $('#username').val() + $('#password').val());
    var invocationData = {
           adapter : 'LoginAdapter',
           procedure : 'getVerify',
           parameters : [ $('#username').val() , $('#password').val() ]
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
           onSuccess : getVerifySuccess,
           onFailure : getVerifyFailure,
    });
};

 function getVerifySuccess(res) {


        var httpStatusCode = res.status;
        if (200 == httpStatusCode) {
               var invocationResult = res.invocationResult;
               var isSuccessful = invocationResult.isSuccessful;
               if (true == isSuccessful) {

                   $("#demo").html(JSON.stringify(res.responseJSON.data));   

          if (res.responseJSON.data== "True "){
                         window.location="pages/view.html";
                     }

                     alert("Success: Value= " + res.responseJSON.data);



               } else {
                     alert("Error. isSuccessful=" + isSuccessful);
               }
        } else {
               alert("Error. httpStatusCode=" + httpStatusCode);
        }

};

function getVerifyFailure(result){
    alert("Verification Failure");
};
```

I would highly appreciate if i can get some help. Thank you.

Comment: I've removed the error log you posted because it is not related. Please add ONLY the error and not a bunch of log from previous attempts. Just the error - preview your application in the browser, open the chrome devtools and copy the error you see there.

Comment: It is working on the Mobilefirst console but not in android virtual emulator.

Comment: Clear your LogCat, do a single attempt at running the application and then upload (to pastebin.com) the logcat contents.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/x184yXdp

Comment: Looks like it's failing with building the response. Provide your project for debugging.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dlea58z5qn2kc0z/file.rar?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The provided sample application worked just fine... I received an alert dialog with the text: "Success: Value=False".

The only difference I can think of, which relates every time in each of your questions... if the IP address. In your provided LogCat, it shows the server's IP address is "10.0.0.3", whereas mine is my actual IP address (9.148.x.y in my case).

As you were previously advised - use the correct IP address of the server in wlclient.properties.

To check for mine, I typed the following in Terminal: ifconfig (in Windows - "ipconfig").

Comment: the project i uploaded on dropbox works. It is just a part of the app. I extracted the parts that did not work and place it in a new project. In in the whole application, it fails.

Comment: Then I don't understand what do you want. Why do you give me something that works?

Comment: It is working fine. The whole application. I freed space on the virtual emulator for the big project. Thank you lots Idan.

Comment: When i do ipcofig on windows, the ip add is "10.0.0.3" since it is auto assign by the router.